# Get a result from First SQL Query to use it at Second SQL Query which is inside First

Tags: java, sql

How to make this one work? Obviously I don't know some very basic staff about SQL queries inside other SQL queries in Java but searching around didn't help!

Thank you in advance

```
        try (Connection con = L2DatabaseFactory.getInstance().getConnection())
        {
            PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement("SELECT count,owner_id FROM items WHERE item_id=57 order by count desc limit 10");
            ResultSet rSet = stm.executeQuery();
            while (rSet.next())
            {
                int owner_id = rSet.getInt("owner_id");
                int count = rSet.getInt("count");
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                PreparedStatement stm1 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT char_name,accesslevel,online FROM characters WHERE obj_Id=" + owner_id);
                ResultSet rSet1 = stm1.executeQuery();
                while (rSet1.next())
                {
                    int accessLevel = rSet.getInt("accesslevel");
                    if (accessLevel > 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String pl = rSet.getString("char_name");
                    int online = rSet.getInt("online");
                    String status = online == 1 ? "<font color=\"00FF00\">Online</font>" : "<font color=\"FF0000\">Offline</font>";                     
                    sb.append("<tr><td>"+ pl +"</td><td>"+ count +"</td><td>"+ status +"</td></tr>");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error", e);
        }
```

Comment: What problem do you have with this code? Any errors? Expected vs actual result etc.

Comment: Error: Column "accesslevel" not found. I think the second PreparedStatement don't even run.
I'm trying to get a value from the first query and use it at the second one to get specific results.

Comment: Well, accesslevel is referred from the second query so it does get executed. Can you recheck the query column name vs actual db column name?

Comment: The error comes from the database, so your second PreparedStatement is definitely run. The column "accesslevel" in table "characters" does not exist, is what the database says. Maybe it's spelled "access_level"?

Comment: Nope it's spelled correctly, if I delete the rSet.getInt("accesslevel"); I'm getting the error at "char_name", If I delete this one too I'm getting it for "online". Something is wrong with the second PreparedStatement.

Comment: Are you able to run the second (inner) query in a database console?

Comment: yeap Vasan, I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to join two tables using Java code. This is not such a great idea and not good for performance. Let the database do the joins for you - it is an expert at that. Do not code "[inner joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))" in Java.

Apart from that: the prepared statements are not being closed and this will sooner or later cause you trouble with OS resources.

My suggestion would be to create one single query with an `inner join` or a `select in` statement and also close all prepared statements using try with resources. Something along these lines:

```
private String test() throws SQLException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;
    try (Connection con = L2DatabaseFactory.getInstance().getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement stm1 = con.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT char_name,accesslevel,online FROM characters WHERE obj_Id in (SELECT owner_id FROM items WHERE item_id=57 order by count desc limit 10)")) {
            ResultSet rSet = stm1.executeQuery();
            while (rSet.next()) {
                count++;
                int accessLevel = rSet.getInt("accesslevel");
                if (accessLevel > 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                String pl = rSet.getString("char_name");
                int online = rSet.getInt("online");
                String status = online == 1 ? "<font color=\"00FF00\">Online</font>" : "<font color=\"FF0000\">Offline</font>";
                sb.append("<tr><td>" + pl + "</td><td>" + count + "</td><td>" + status + "</td></tr>");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger("test").log(Level.SEVERE, "Error", e);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: yeap, this is what I need but my "count" is column at items.
[Image if it helps](https://i.imgur.com/8V6sf4A.png)
It's how many of item_id=57 the character has.
I'm trying to get the Top 10 count of item_id=57 and sort them desc

Comment: @GeorgeTagas: You could use a "select in" statement for that instead of the inner join. See the updated answer for an example ...

Comment: yeah, I changed it a little bit for my use and it worked like a charm. Thank you buddy!

Comment: @GeorgeTagas:  Cool, glad to hear that.